# In SQL how do I do SUMIF for specific criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with three columns, ID, Date, Value.

I want to do a SUMIF so that given ID, SUM(Value) if Date is in between some range.  In other words:

```
SUM(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Date > X and Date < Y)
```

How do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use conditional aggregation here with a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SUM(CASE WHEN Date > X AND Date < Y THEN Value ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID)
```

If you instead wish to *aggregate* together all `ID` records and report a single record for each `ID`, then use the above call to `SUM` but remove the `OVER` clause.  For example:

```sql
SELECT
    ID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Date > X AND Date < Y THEN Value ELSE 0 END) AS the_sum
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID;
```